# Compare a large wordlist for matches in a mysql table of valid words

Tags: mysql

I have a large wordlist like this:

```
('Mill','Test','Report','Stainless','Pipe','Commodity','Steel','Welded','Pipe','Customer','Destination','Los Angeles','Specification','Country','Grade','Customer', ...)
```

And a MySQL table of words with one column ("word").

How can I pass my wordlist into the query and have returned those words that:

- exist (at least once) in the table
- don't exist in the table

---

NOTE:

```
SELECT word FROM englishwords WHERE word IN('Mill','Test','Report','Stainless','Pipe','Commodity','Steel','Welded','Pipe','Customer','Destination','Los Angeles','Specification','Country','Grade','Customer') GROUP BY word
```

This works for returning the words that EXIST in the table.

I suppose I could array_diff the before and after, but I was hoping there would be a way to do it simply with one query.

I'll try @barmar recommendation to just create temporary tables for each operation, too.

Comment: You want to receive the words provided in output list as output values - so they must be data, not criteria. You may send your list into the query as a rowset, or you may parse solid values list (provided as CSV or JSON) to rowser in a query using recursive CTE or JSON_TABLE function.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: Create another table that has your wordlist. Then find the words in that table that aren't in `englishwords`.

Comment: i don't think this question need [tag:cpu-word] as it refers to machine-level instruction..

Answer (score 1):

You want to put your input into a table and then use [an outer join](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/homepage/mysql-joins/).

Inner joins return only those rows that exist in both tables.

Outer joins return all the records from the first table and records from the joined table, or null if they do not exist.